# Get a count of combinations and its reverse from two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get a count of combinations from a pandas dataframe where it views reversed form of the combinations as the same. ie (A/B will be the same as B/A)

Similar to what this user is trying to do, but on python/pandas

[How to get count of two-way combinations from two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578075/how-to-get-count-of-two-way-combinations-from-two-columns)

Thank you for helping!

I've explored crosstabs and grouping the data and it produces a count of the combinations, but it sees the reverse order as a unique combination.

```
Origin    Destination
City 1    City 2
City 2    City 1
City 3    City 4
City 2    City 1
```

End result will look like

```
Route                 Count
City 1 - City 2         3
City 3 - City 4         1
```

note: order of the route does not matter. It could be City 2 - City 1, as long as it counts it as the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a route using `np.sort`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['Route'] = [' - '.join(x) for x in np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1)]
df.groupby('Route').size()

#Route
#City 1 - City 2    3
#City 3 - City 4    1
#dtype: int64
```

---

You can also construct a new sorted `DataFrame`, which could be useful:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

#   Origin Destination
#0  City 1      City 2
#1  City 1      City 2
#2  City 3      City 4
#3  City 1      City 2
```

Now you can groupby `['Origin', 'Destintion']`

Answer (score 1):

Check with `sort`

```
df.values.sort()
df.groupby(list(df)).size()
Origin  Destination
City1   City2          3
City3   City4          1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Note that `df.values.sort()` sorts the dataframe inplace! If this is not the desired result, better to make a copy of the original dataframe: `df2 = df.copy(); df2.values.sort()` and work on `df2` instead.